# Configure distributed DCOM

Tags: windows, server, dcom

Im trying to allow another computer in the same network so acces a server I have local on my computer.

As far as I know, this should be administrated in Componentservices (accesing it by running dcomcnfg.exe). I then rightclick on My Computer and click on the Properties option. Then i click on the tab called Standardproperties and then I check "Activate distributed COM on this computer".

Then I go to COM-safety and click on EDIT. But Distrubuted COM is not in that list for me to administer.

What am I missing?

Comment: *Configure distributed DCOM* Is that like DCOM but even more distributed?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771387.aspx

As they write on point 4: "Enable Distributed COM on this computer". That link shows how to disable it, wich I dont want to do. Just an example of the naming convention